# C++ does a class construct members on class construction?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I do have a struct

```
struct MyStruct {
    MyStruct( XML cfg ) { ... }
    int m_1, m_2, ... ;
}
```

And a class

```
class MyBaseClass {
    public:
    MyBaseClass() {}     
    MyStruct m_struct;
}

class MyClass : public MyBaseClass {
    public:
    MyClass( XML cfg ) { m_struct = MyStruct( cfg ); }        
}
```

Now the compiler is complaining that MyStruct does not have an empty constructor

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘MyStruct::MyStruct()’
 MyClass( XML cfg ) { m_struct = MyStruct( cfg ); }
```

I dont think teh inheritance plays a role ehre, but I kept it for completeness as it may be the case. I never explicitly call an empty constructor for MyStruct. Does the class MyClass do that because m_struct is its member?
If that is teh case, is there a way to not have it initialize the member or is this only possible with pointers as members?

I am aware I can fix this by just adding an empty constructor to my structure or by changing the constructor to

```
MyClass( XML cfg ) : m_struct = MyStruct( cfg ) {}
```

but I am curious to know what exactly is going on here.

Comment: `struct` and `class` are the same. They don't form useful categories here.

Comment: I use a struct because it only contains a couple of public members. the class itself contains a lot more than my example here, I just try to be minimalsitic in my example

Comment: Inheritance indeed plays no role here. You can completely remove  MyClass, instantiate MyBaseClass, and have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @chrise Yes, I think I misread the question. But if you want to be minimalistic, you can use `struct` for everything. It involves less typing (you don't have to say `public` everywhere.

Comment: You can find a very good answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does a class construct members on class construction?

Of course yes. The issue occurs at the constructor of `MyBaseClass`, which doesn't initialize the member `m_struct` explicitly, then it will be default initialized, but `MyStruct` doesn't have a default constructor.

This is true not only for the data member, also for the base class object. For the constructor of `MyClass`, it doesn't explicitly specify the constructor of the base class, then the default constructor of `MyBaseClass` will be invoked, then cause the error as the above explained.

You can add a default constructor for `MyStruct`, or use [member intializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) at the constructor of `MyBaseClass`, to call `MyStruct::MyStruct( XML cfg )` explicitly to intialize the member `m_struct`. e.g.

```
MyBaseClass() : m_struct(some_thing) {}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasnt aware of that. I happened to use smart pointers as members that the instance itself, so in my few weeks of tinkering with c++ I actually never stumbled across that issue

Comment: @chrise Smart pointers can be default constructed; so everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you omit the member initializer, the compiler will insert one using no arguments. Hence the error.

This also means that in your first extract where you initialize the member inside the constructor body, the member gets initialized twice, if the compiler permits. Don't write code like this.